# WPF Datagrid: Splitting Cell Value and converting it to different objects

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to create a Calendar type DataGrid. Here, I don't know what will be my columns, so I have to use AutoGenerateColumns = true. Since my columns are returned from Database, I don't think I can bind it with Collection and define my datacolumns here (please correct me if I am wrong).

I made some Sample project for explaining.

WPF Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="467.241" Width="892.586">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="dtMainGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dtMainGrid" Margin="10,10,9.667,9.667" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.28,-4.862"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DateTime start = new DateTime(2015,1,1);
            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(start.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
                table.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.Rows.Add();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    row[i] = "8:30;9:30;10.30";
                }
            }

            dtMainGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dtMainGrid.DataContext = table;
        }

        private void dtMainGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }


    public class TestItem
    {
        public string Text;

    }

    }
```

It creates the following UI:

[image: My Sample Window Layout]

Now, I need to do this. I need to split the cell value by semi-colon and replace it with a Red color circle shape. Well, obviously, this is a sample so you seeing same values in each cell, but in real time data, you will see different data in different cells. You may not even see any data for a particular cell so it is not static in anyways.

Since I am binding the DataContext with a DataTable. I am not sure how can I do that. I am not able to get a starting point. Any pointers will be great.

Comment: Have you considered/are you open to creating a view model layer to define the presentation logic for the data within the `DataTable`? That would allow you to expose new properties extremely easily.

Comment: hey I am sorry i dont know what view model layer is. I will google it.

Comment: This code doesn't create UI shows in the picture. No values in grid cells and give data binding error in output.. are you missing something?

Comment: I don't think the code is wrong. I posted a working project here.